# Spring on WebSphere 8: Quartz job with web service call throws JAXBException "<class> is not known to this context"

Tags: spring, jaxb, websphere

I'm facing a JAXBException " is not known to this context" when calling a web service from within a job controlled by Quartz on Spring:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:   com.xxxx.yyyy.zzzz.ImageMetaData is not known to this context
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalResponse(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:624)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:593)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy299.findAllImageMetaData(Unknown Source)
```

I'm having a Spring 3.2.4 Java EE application with JSF running on IBM WebSphere v8.
When calling a specific web service from the JSF part of the application (i.e. from an action or a service), everything's ok.
The exception occurs only when the call is done from within a Quartz/Spring triggered job.
Executing exacty the same job code from the action does not result in an exception.

I tried a lot of different things like using a corresponding @XmlSeeAlso annotation in the JAXB generated classes but even using the annotation in the webservice interface itself does not solve the issue.

I also updated the Spring and Quartz libraries to more recent versions but this didn't help.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Check this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM51464

Comment: I'm using IBM Websphere 8.0.0.6 which should contain the fix covering this issue. Besides this issue is about inner classes. In my case the indicated classes are just normal classes.

Comment: Anyone who has further hints..?

Comment: I've finally solved the issue. after much analysis

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved the issue.
After much analysis I encountered the following issue in the Spring framework:

https://jira.spring.io/i#browse/SPR-11125

When a job is triggered via Spring/Quartz on WebSphere, the wrong ContextClassLoader is set.
This may cause many different problems - among them is the JAXBException as described.

The Spring bug is still open - so as a workaround I had to overwrite the context class loader of the current thread by the correct one:

```
ClassLoader cl = invoiceService.getClass().getClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
```

The correct class loader can be simply retrieved by a class that has been loaded by the container. Using this class loader as the context class loader for the current thread solved my issue.